# fullpage.js - unable to click links on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js on a site and when you view it on mobile the anchor links are not clickable and input fields are not accessible.

Also when I set "responsiveWidth: 640" to disable fullpage on mobile I am no longer able to scroll down or move past the first section on my phone and still can't click any links.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

** **EDIT** **
This is a WordPress site using the skeleton theme "JointsWP"

Here is the site that this is happening on http://jbirdco.com/

Comment: [An answer](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2578) was given to you on the Github issues forum of fullPage.js
Make sure to use the latest version. If you still having troubles provide an isolated reproduction for further investigation.

Comment: @Alvaro I am using the latest version of fullPage.js. There is no way for me to provide an isolated reproduction being that this is a WordPress site. I can give you the live link to the page that this is happening on though. The link is above.